# SilverStripe - Prevent HTML Bookmarks from returning to homepage

Tags: html, anchor, silverstripe

I have been trying to figure out how to get conventional HTML bookmarks to work on a SilverStripe site. I have them working somewhat correctly in that they do navigate to the correct divs. However, all bookmarks are navigating to the proper section on homepage, which is incorrect.

For example, I have a button at the bottom of each page in the footer that is meant to take the user back to the top of the page:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <a href="#top" class="toTop"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-100 mobile-grid-100 tablet-grid-100">
            <h3>Back to top</h3>
              <span class="copyright">&copy; $Now.Year<br></span></div>
    </div><!-- close container -->
</footer>
```

However, when clicking the "Back to Top" button on a subpage, the user is taken to the top of the home page. The same thing happens with the "Contact Us" section links--you are always taken back to the homepage's "Contact Us" section. But this is not what I want. The bookmarks should keep the users on the page that they are on.

I put this line of code in the config.yml file:

SSViewer:
  rewrite_hash_links: false

That stopped the bookmarks from being treated like website urls, but that hasn't fixed everything it seems. Is there something I can add to the .yml file to prevent bookmarks on subpages from returning to the homepage?

EDIT: Disabling JavaScript does NOT fix the issue, so it's not server-side related. The issue occurs in Chrome, FireFox, Safari, and IE, so it doesn't seem to be browser specific.

Comment: You did this https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/templates/how_tos/disable_anchor_links/ . Did you run http://example.com?flush=all ? If you change the yml values (remember to log in as an admin) you need to flush the config caches. E.g. if the outputted source code is still contains the site url there it's not working right.

Comment: Does this work for you: `<a href="{$Link}#top" class="toTop"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see I believe all you need to do for your case is just use the `ID` of the div in the `href` that should take you to the top of the page to where you have your `<div id="top"></div>`.

**E.g**

```
<footer class="footer">
    <a href="#top" class="toTop"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-100 mobile-grid-100 tablet-grid-100">
            <h3>Back to top</h3>
              <span class="copyright">&copy; $Now.Year<br></span></div>
    </div><!-- close container -->
</footer>
```

Also this is called HTML anchor link's not bookmarks: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.htm

Comment: I tried this but I had the same issue I had before--I am always taken back to the homepage. I go to the right section, but it's always on the homepage. It's like the anchor link is still being treated like a URL.

Comment: On an important side note, this does not appear to be browser-specific, and disabling JS does NOT fix the issue.

Comment: It seems that there was some kind of unknown issue as I did resolve this with the rewrite_hash_links = false bit. Why it wasn't working before, I have no idea but things seem to be working now.